# Elasticsearch sorting - not getting expected results

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I have data in elastic field name as "Amit 111", "amit 111", "Amit 222".

I am trying to sort it using:

```
   searchSourceBuilder.query(query).sort("name.keyword", SortOrder.ASC)
```

It returns result as:
"Amit 111", "Amit 222", "amit 111"

But I want results as :
"Amit 111", "amit 111", "Amit 222"

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use the [fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html) as on `text` field you can apply the sort, more details on the linked URL.

**Java code for that you need to change the index mapping as shown after java code.**

```
searchSourceBuilder.query(query).sort("name", SortOrder.ASC)
```

### Create index with field data enabled on the `name` field

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": { 
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

### Index example documents

```
{
  "name" : "amit 111"
}

{
  "name" : "Amit 111"
}

{
  "name" : "Amit 222"
}
```

### Your search query with sort on `name` field

```
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "name": "asc"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Result

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "key",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "amit 111"
        },
        "sort": [
          "111"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "key",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Amit 111"
        },
        "sort": [
          "111"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "key",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Amit 222"
        },
        "sort": [
          "222"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: but fieldData causes an overhead and is expensive as far as I could infer.

Comment: @amitkumarsingh thanks for your comment, yeah it's expensive but if you don't have much data its OK, this option is given by Elasticsearch and again it depends on your use-case to use it or not :)

Comment: @amitkumarsingh also enabling field data. isn't much overhead(wrt to code complexity). Also it would be great if you can accept and upvote answer as it solves the problem, TIA :)

Answer (score 1):

keyword fields are stored as it is so sorting on keyword fields is case sensitive.[Normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html) with lowercase filter can be used to index keyword fields.

> The normalizer property of keyword fields is similar to analyzer
>   except that it guarantees that the analysis chain produces a single
>   token.

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query:** Both sort on name.keyword and term query on name.keyword will be case insensitive

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "name.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Result:**"

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index84",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "SBvLT3IB8mx5yKbJQ7EC",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Amit 111"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "amit 111"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index84",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "SRvLT3IB8mx5yKbJULFl",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "amit 111"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "amit 111"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index84",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ShvLT3IB8mx5yKbJaLFg",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Amit 222"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "amit 222"
        ]
      }
    ]
```